# NestedScrollview overlapping CollapsingToolbarLayout like gmusic app

Tags: android, material-design, android-design-library, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I would like to replicate the behavior of the google play music android app.
In that app when you use "My music" album tab, the list of albums starts Over the actionbar (the orange part) as it is "extended". When you scroll up the albums list, that orange part scroll up but more slowly than the list.
When you scroll down the list the "orange block" also scrolls down.
This behavior is independent of the toolbar and tabs being scrolled.

I'm trying to reproduce such behavior with the new material design library.
Using as a starting point the detail activity xml from Cheesquare:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"      
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backdrop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="24dp">
        <....>
       </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I have tried to use the backdrop "imageview" with a color background, and try to move it alongside the nestedview.
If I put the imageview inside the CollapsingToolbarLayout with a parallax effect, the problem is that I can't make its heigh bigger to be under the nestedscrollview.
If I put the imageview outside the collapsingToolbarLayout but inside the NestedScrollView, I can't change the "velocity" of the viewScrolling.
If I put the imageview outside the NestedScrollview, it is drawn over the toolbar even when the toolbar is pined.

Before the material design library, I used a view and a callback to the scrollview to move it up and down, but I want to use the new library as it very clean its remove a lot of boilerplate code.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

In fact, overlaying the scrolling view with the AppBarLayout doesn't require any of that: you can use the `app:behavior_overlayTop` attribute on your `NestedScrollView` to set the overlap amount:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    app:behavior_overlapTop="64dp">
```

Note that `app:behavior_overlapTop` only works on views that have the `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` as it is the Behavior that is using the attribute (not the View or the Parent ViewGroup, as attributes usually apply to), hence the `behavior_` prefix.

Or set it programmatically via [setOverlayTop()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior.html#setOverlayTop(int)):

```
NestedScrollView scrollView = ...
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = 
    (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) scrollView.getLayoutParams();
AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior behavior =
    (AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior) params.getBehavior();
behavior.setOverlayTop(128); // Note: in pixels
```

Comment: This would solve to have the scrollview over the "toolbar", but in the gmusic, the toolbar is "splited" it two parts: the normal toolbar that hides as "material design specs", and the "extended" toolbar that is under the scrollview and scroll up slower than the scrool view. So when you scroll up, the "normal" toolbar hides, and the other is still being show. When you scroll down, the "normal" toolbar appears with elevation over the "scroll view + extended toolbar" and when the scroll is 0, the normal and the extended are blended.

Comment: @ianhanniballake  Intercepting Touch Event Nested Scroll View EditTexts and Spinners. I have layout with couple of Edit text and Spinners. Nested Scroll view not scrolling smoothly.

Comment: `app:behavior_overlayTop` should be `app:behavior_overlapTop`

Comment: @JasonHu - good catch - I had changed it in the paragraph following the code, but missed it in the code itself - I've corrected it now.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I was stuck forever trying to get the overlap to work. Turns out I had to use the scroll flag 'enterAlwaysCollapsed|. Without it the nested scrollview was just docked under the appbarLayout